# Swift using if on an enum resulting in error not convertible to '_ArrayCastKind'

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm using Beta 3 of xcode 6, and I am having a problem doing a simple if statement against an enum passed into an argument of a closure.  Here is the simple enum definition:

```
enum FLSTeslaLoginStatus {
    case LoggedOut
    case LoggedIn
    case LoggingIn
    case LoginFailed(NSData!, NSHTTPURLResponse!, NSError)
}
```

And the code with the error is:

[image]

As you can see the switch statement works fine, but the if check is resulting in the error.  This is just some test code so I won't normally have a switch and an if statement, but I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with the if statement.  I'm thinking it is a compiler bug.

This is supported in Swift 2.0 with the use of "if case".

Comment: looks like if any case of the enum have associated value, you must use switch-statement to test it. time to file a bug report (at least the error message need to be meaningful). Also get same error when compare the enum to itself. i.e. `t == t`.

Comment: Oddly, I get the error if I use the shortcut `.LoggedIn`, but not if it's fully qualified.

Comment: It's almost certainly a bug, file a radar.

Comment: Kevin, I get the same. Works fine if fully qualified.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Swift 2.x allows this via the if case pattern match: https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-2-pattern-matching-with-if-case/

```
if case let .LoggedIn(name,password) = status  {
   print( "\(name) Logged in!" )
}
```

Answer (score 6):

At this time (iOS8 Beta 4) it seems you need to fully-quality the enum value when doing an == comparison.

**OK:**

```
if (taskSortOrder == TaskSortOrder.Name) {
    ...
}
```

**Error:** *"TaskSortOrder' is not convertible to 'Selector'"*

```
if (taskSortOrder == .Name) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens in my enum example also, but i'm using Int type

```
enum DisplayFunctionKey : Int {
     case Auto, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
}

var key : DisplayFunctionKey = .Auto;

if key == .Auto { /* do your stuff */ } // gives error
```

But! ... strangely enough with using not operator in if statement with accompanying else it works:

```
if key != .Auto {} else { /* do your stuff */ } // this works
```

It's kinda ugly, but rather one else more, than the whole switch real estate for just one line check.

Answer (score -1):

You're supposed to use the switch statement with enums.

```
switch task order {
case .Name:
   ...
default:
   break
}
```

Comment: Switch is one way to access the value of an enum.  For example, "if let" is a fine way to access the value of an enum with associated types.